# Attachment URLs incomplete on remote server only

Tags: api, attachments

I'm working locally on my Mac with the latest version of CiviCRM on latest WordPress, served by MAMP. Using the API, I create an attachment to a contact, and those attachments successfully display after being retrieved through the API. The URL comes back as `http://localhost/civicrm?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Ffile&reset=1&id=15&eid=29&fcs=...`

However, when I upload the code and database records to the remote server for testing, the one thing that doesn't work are my attachments. The URLs come back from the API missing a slash: `http://remotedomain.comcivicrm?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Ffile&reset=1&id=15&eid=29&fcs=...` Notice the missing slash after the `.com?

I've double checked the configuration in civicrm.settings.php. Both localhost and remotedomain.com have a / in the URL base. I checked the various settings in the admin interface, but nothing looks amiss.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Just a thought: Is the remote server linux or windows?

Comment: I'm assuming Linux since the paths begin with /home/username/

Comment: Ok it was just a thought. It seems to work ok on wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org, using the api explorer, so it makes me think it would be something to do with config somewhere.

Comment: A configuration issue seems to be the likely explanation, right!?
But I export the DB from localhost to remote, swapping in the domain with find-and-replace. And I upload the config file as-is, with code that inserts `http://localhost/` or `http://remotedomain.com/` as applicable with the terminal slashes. So what gives...?

Answer (score 1):

Can you check

1. Check if base url in civicrm.settings.php file is set 'http://remotedomain.com/'.
2. Try setting home and siteurl in wp_options table to 'http://remotedomain.com/' (not needed for normal install).

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: `civicrm.settings.php` has a value for `CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL` that is set for the correct remote URL, including the last `/`

`wp_options` already has both values set with the correct remote domain, including the `/` at the end.

Comment: How about in  civicrm.settings.php?

Comment: Return submitting and not doing a line return in comments always gets me

Comment: I may have discovered a bug. I `print_f`d the globals `$civicrm_root, $civicrm_setting, $civicrm_paths` and saw on the remote server that even though `[wp.frontend.base]` was defined in `civicrm.settings.php` with the slash (I could see it _right there_ in the variable definition), it was being dropped. So I added another slash. Then there were two! So I removed one, and now it's working...!